# Aligning a table to the very left of a div

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'm trying to make a 2x2 grid, which fills up the entire window in an iPhone, with a table.
Currently it looks like this:http://dl.dropbox.com/u/182509/photo.PNG

Note the squshed-uppy-ness of the right column, and the gap at the left.

I cant fix either.

Relevant css:

```
body { margin: 0; position: absolute; height: 100%; }

.full { position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: white; }

table { border-width: 0px; border-spacing: 0px; border-style: hidden; border-color: gray; border-collapse: collapse; background-color: white; width: 100%; height: 100%; left: 0; top: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 0px; position: absolute; }

td { border-width: 1px; padding: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: gray; background-color: white; width: 50%; height: 160px; }
```

and html:

```
<div id="helpView" class="full">
    <table id="help">
        <tr>
            <td>Hey..</td>
            <td>Hi.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello.</td>
            <td>Greetings!</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: try adding tr { width: 100%; padding: 0px; }

Comment: reduce width of the td as 48%

Comment: That didn't work... same as before (to both of you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `td` has border set to 1px, it adds to the total width of what we are seeing, so you have to reduce the width of your `td`. See box model for reference:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html

or you can set the `left` of your table to `-1` to adjust it to left:

```
table{left:-1}
```

it will work since the position is absolute.

Comment: Dosen't seem to work. Could the problem be related to the fact that `.full` has the property: `display: none;` and is being faded in with JQuery?

Comment: Never ever link to w3schools. it's evil (most of the information there is WRONG and MISLEADING).

Comment: Not the one I gave about box model, I think.

Comment: There are plenty other sources. You should never send someone still learning to there.

Comment: @Rikudo see edit. I thought W3.org will give him a novel-like article :)

Answer (score 0):

You've overcomplicated things.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z3rs5/

You should write simple code, also, do't cram all of the CSS statements in one row, every time you do that, God kills a kitten!

Comment: I had to cram all my css into 1 row because of a StackOverflow formatting issue, it is all nicely spread out in my code.

Comment: Alright, did you see the jsfiddle though? position: absolute; can and should be used, but you don't need to add the border on the TDs, add them as an attribute to the table and use border-collapse;